# How can I relate a JProgressBar with other component?

Tags: java, swing

I need to show the progress bar when i click in a button and the progress is related with the information that shows a jtextpane.

this is the method of the progress bar

```
private JProgressBar getMethodsjProgressBar() {
    if (methodsjProgressBar == null) {
        methodsjProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
        methodsjProgressBar.setVisible(false);
        methodsjProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        methodsjProgressBar.setBounds(new Rectangle(20, 244, 103, 22));
        methodsjProgressBar.setString("Cargando...");
    }
    return methodsjProgressBar;
}
```

and this one is the button

```
private JButton getLoadMethodsButton() {
    if (loadMethodsButton == null) {
        loadMethodsButton = new JButton();
        loadMethodsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                FileChooserDirectory.getInstance().getAddress();
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                LoadClass loadClass = new LoadClass();
                methodsjProgressBar.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        loadMethodsButton.setText("Buscar clase");
        loadMethodsButton.setBounds(237, 255, 126, 26);
    }
    return loadMethodsButton;
}
```

i need to know what i have to do to change the jprogressbar value when i'm loading the class

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very unclear. Please provide more pertinent detail and pertinent code. Also, it appears to be a Swing question, and so I've added a Swing tag to the question, but why the Eclipse and especially the Eclipse-plugin tags? The question appears to have nothing to do with Eclipse plugins.

Comment: @Danay: Where are you calling 'getMethodsjProgressBar' method in your java class. Only I am getting is in 'getLoadMethodsButton' you are trying to show that progressbar.

Comment: what i need to do is change the percentage of the progress bar while the jtextpane is loading the content, sorry but it's difficult to me explain all this in english so be patient, and thanks for the recommendations

Comment: i haven't call that method yet

Comment: Did you look at the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Do any file input/output in a background thread so as not to tie up the Swing event thread.
- A SwingWorker would work nicely for your background thread.
- One way to monitor the reading in of information is to use a [ProgressMonitorInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) which will display a dialog if the reading in through the Stream takes any appreciable time.
- Otherwise if you want to use a JProgressBar, then inside the SwingWorker, set the progress property via `setProgress(...)` to a value between 0 and 100, add a PropertyChangeListener to your SwingWorker and listen for changes to the progress property, and then use this data to update your JProgressBar.
- A side recommendation: Avoid using `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)` since this will result in very rigid GUI's that are difficult to update or maintain.

If you need more detailed help, consider creating and posting a minimal example program

Comment: ok, thanks i'm going to try and i tell you later if it's worked